# Error when using the logs in Quarkus with logger jboss

Tags: java, logging, jboss, quarkus

Good afternoon, I have a query, I am starting in Quarkus and I have a problem with the use of logs in it, I am working with a simple service that uses the GET verb, when placing the line of logs it throws me an error of java.lang.NullPointerException. This is my main code:

```
package com.tmve.subscriber;

import com.tmve.subscriber.repository.FindPrepaidSubscriberICCIDRepository;
import io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.HashMap;


@Path("/api")
public class FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID {

    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource defaultDataSource;
    Logger log;
    FindPrepaidSubscriberICCIDRepository repository= new FindPrepaidSubscriberICCIDRepository();
    private final String movil="142910399";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public HashMap<String,String> hello() {
        HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
        map=repository.getResources(defaultDataSource,movil);
        log.info("movil: "+movil);
        return map;
    }
}
```

My application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
#quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
#quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=io.opentracing.contrib.jdbc.TracingDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.xx.2.xxx:1522/IVR
quarkus.datasource.username=${USERNAME_CONNECTION_BD:psp}
quarkus.datasource.password=${PASSWORD_CONNECTION_BD:xxxxxxxxx}
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}
quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."org.hibernate".level=DEBUG

# Send output to a trace.log file under the /tmp directory
quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/trace.log
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
# Configure a named handler that logs to console
quarkus.log.handler.console."STRUCTURED_LOGGING".format=%e%n
# Configure a named handler that logs to file
quarkus.log.handler.file."STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE".format=%e%n
# Configure the category and link the two named handlers to it
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.category".level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.category".handlers=STRUCTURED_LOGGING,STRUCTURED_LOGGING_FILE
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tmve.subscriber</groupId>
  <artifactId>find-prepaid-subscriber-iccid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.10.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j2-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.22</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Error:

```
14:28:22 ERROR [io.qu.ve.ht.ru.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /api failed, error id: 85c7bf48-6300-4c29-b93a-74f3532832d8-3: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledExcepti
on: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.logging.Logger.info(Object)" because "this.log" is null
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:91)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:554)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jboss.logging.Logger.info(Object)" because "this.log" is null
        at com.tmve.subscriber.FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID.hello(FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID.java:29)
        at com.tmve.subscriber.FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID_Subclass.hello$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at com.tmve.subscriber.FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID_Subclass$$function$$3.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:53)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:40)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at com.tmve.subscriber.FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID_Subclass.hello(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 15 more
```

[image]

What could be happening, I don't understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not injecting the logger. You can change the code to:

```
    @Inject
    AgroalDataSource defaultDataSource;

    @Inject
    Logger log;
```

By the way, Quarkus [offers an additional way to get the logger](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-with-panache) without injection:

```
package com.example;

import io.quarkus.logging.Log; 

class MyService { 
    public void doSomething() {
        Log.info("Simple!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Davide answer is totally right, I just wanted to add that you can use *constructor* injection:

```java
private final AgroalDataSource ds;
private final Logger log;

public FindPrepaidSubscriberICCID(AgroalDataSource ds, Logger log) {
   this.ds = ds;
   this.log = log;
}
```

Constructor injection tends to ease testability (because you can create instances of your objects passing spies or mocks). It also makes sure you do not write to the *managed* fields (as the fields are final).

Comment: Thank you. You mean that is good practice use this method that davide's answer? Why?

Comment: I think it's an option. You could also define alternatives using CDI. But, going back to the original question, I don't think you plan to mock the logger.

Comment: By the way, you don't even need to inject the logger: https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-with-panache

Comment: IT's just a question of taste. Initially, I was only using field injection, these days, I'm using constructor injection. As I said, it makes testing easier. But, again, a question of taste.